# iterating in two arrays in the same for loop

Tags: php, html, web

I'm learning php and I want to know how to iterate in two arrays in the same for loop? This is the code I have, line 8  to line 14 for example, but it gives an array instead of an element, what to do? please be easy on me I'm still new to this field.

```
<tr>
<td><?php echo $val->title ?></td>
<td><?php echo $val->content?></td>
<td><?php echo $val->owner ?></td>
<?php } ?>

<?php
foreach ($users as $val) {
?>
<td><?php echo str_replace("-", "%", $val->email) ?></td>
<?php }?>
<?php foreach ($maincat as $val) {?>
<td><?php echo str_replace("-","%",$val->maincat_name) ?></td>
<?php }?>

<?php foreach ($category as $val) {?>
<td><?php echo str_replace("-","%",$val->category_name) ?></td>
<?php }?>

<?php foreach ($sub_category as $val) {?>
<td><?php echo str_replace("-","%",$val->sub_category_name) ?></td>
<?php }?>

<?php foreach ($sub_sub_category as $val) {?>
<td><?php echo str_replace("-","%",$val->sub_sub_category_name) ?></td>
<?php }?>

</tr>
```

In this image, it gives the whole cells

[image]

instead of the two cells `{sajeda@sajeda.com and email2}` , I want the cell *sajeda@sajeda.com* to be in the bottom and the other one *email*2 to be above.

This is not an html question, when iterating, **I want the first value** to be **sajeda@sajdea.com** and the other iteration to give **email2**

can somebody help ?

EDIT :

this is how i define users

```
$data['users'] = $this->model->join_users($table)->result();
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do. Please provided desired output based on example input.

Comment: You can't iterate 2 arrays at same time. You either need to merge them or you need to iterate one array and search the other for the correct value

Comment: in this image, it gives the whole cells http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=98538 ,,,,, instead of the two cells {sajeda@sajeda.com and email2} , i want the cell sajeda@sajeda.com to be in the bottom and the other one email2 to be above, it's not an html question, i mean, when iteratiting, i want the first value to be sajeda@sajdea.com and the other iteration give email2

Comment: Please do a **var_dump($users);** or **var_dump($data['users']);** immediately before the first **foreach($users as $val)** and show us what you get. In your example you are iterating thru 4 independent arrays.

Comment: Where does `$val->title` and others come from? What is `$data['users']` used for?

Comment: Please, when using PHP as a 'templating language', which is really good!  Use [Alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).

Comment: some php guy solved this for me, please close this x_x

Comment: "Questions with open bounties cannot be deleted"
anyways, i reported it.

Comment: Maybe you can post the solution here for everyone to see, just answer the question yourself

Comment: In the future, I recommend posting a *very clear* question. This question is incredibly vague and will likely not prove useful for anyone else who browses SO.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know is this what you're looking for?

I used a couple shorthands such as `<?=`

to replace `<?php echo` and using `foreach(...) : endforeach;`

```
<?php $i = 0; ?>
<?php foreach ($users as $val) : ?>
  <td><?= str_replace("-", "%", $val->email) ?></td>
  <td><?= str_replace("-", "%", $maincat[$i]->maincat_name) ?></td>
  <td><?= str_replace("-", "%", $category[$i]->category_name) ?></td>
  <td><?= str_replace("-", "%", $sub_category[$i]->sub_category_name) ?></td>
  <td><?= str_replace("-", "%", $sub_sub_category[$i]->sub_sub_category_name) ?></td>
  <?php $i++; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

result() as $msg):?>
                        db->select("lastname, firstname,mi")->from("tb_employee")->where("employee_id",$msg->sender)->get(); ?>

```
                    <a href=<?php echo base_url() ."mainx/show_msg_id/". $msg->msg_id; ?>  >  
                               <?php foreach($s->result() as $t):?>               
                        <div>
                            <strong><?php echo $t->lastname . ' ' . $t->firstname;?></strong>                            
                            <span class="pull-right text-muted">
                                <em><?php echo date('m/d/Y H:i:s' ,$msg->timestamp); ?></em>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div><?php echo $msg->message;?></div>
                    </a>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

---

What i do in my example is that i am loop to foreach. On my first loop is the name of employee and in between of my employee loop is the message foreach loop.